# getting SHA keys for android on windows

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to run `keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore` on windows 10 but wwhen I run it in command prompt it give error `Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore`.

What is the path of keystore filein window

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using "/" (forward-slash) instead of "\" (backslash) to specify the path. Use

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the correct path for the keystore. Something similar to this...

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\"WINDOWS MACHINE USERNAME"\.android\debug.keystore"
```